# Apply a rbind or bind_rows conditionally to a list based on name

Tags: r

Given a list of data.frame like this:

```r
list_dfs <- list(a = mtcars, b = quakes, a = mtcars, c = USArrests)

names(list_dfs)
#> [1] "a" "b" "a" "c"
```

How would I apply a function by the name of the data.frame in the list? Specifically I would like to `rbind` together the data.frames called `a` in this case such that the resulting list had only three elements. If I wnated bind them all I'd do it like this:

```r
do.call(rbind, list_dfs)
#> Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...): numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

Obviously that doesn't work. This does work if the columns do match.

```r
list_mtcars <- list(a = mtcars, a = mtcars)
mt_bound <- do.call(rbind, list_mtcars)
```

What I am wondering if how to replicate the `do.call` & `rbind` piece conditionally so that only those elements of the list named `a` are bound by rows.

Any tidyverse or base R solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `bind_rows` after splitting the `list` by the `names` of the list

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
split(list_dfs, names(list_dfs)) %>%
   map(bind_rows)
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
lapply(split(list_dfs, names(list_dfs)), function(dat) do.call(rbind, unname(dat)))
```

Comment: Probably not explaining myself well. That will bind every elements of the list. I only want to bind those that have the same name.

Comment: Always forget about split! Thanks!